# Importar blogger a una pagina en concreto de wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Pues tengo que hacer esa migración, pero la web que he hecho en wordpress tiene un apartado específico para el "blog", si he especificado esa página como "pagina de entradas" el contenido de blogger se migrará directamente ahí? donde me va a aparecer el nuevo contenido importado?

Answer (score 1):

El contenido que importes va a colocarse en la tabla `_posts` y los vas a poder presentar en donde tu quieras. Si definiste una p'agina de blog, ahi van a aparecer ordenados en orden cronol'ogico. Puedes convertir esa p'agina en tu p'agina inicial.

Pero ojo, no te confundas con el lugar donde se migran. En wordpress no existen las p'aginas como en un sitio tradicional, solo son rutas, donde se presenta la informaci'on.

Por ejemplo, esas entradas migradas aparecer'an en la ruta del autor, del año, de las etiquetas que contengan, de la categor'ia, etc., sin que existan en cada una de esas rutas.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me has solucionado una pregunta pero me has generado otras... jejejjej Con lo de las rutas... Si los posts importados me van a aparecer en la pagina de entradas  que es lo que implica eso de las entradas aparecerán en la ruta del autor, categorías, etc?

Comment: Pues asi funciona WordPress, antes de ser un CMS era un gestor de blogs, donde cada post tiene un autor y se pueden ver los post agrupados por autor. Como se trata de blogs, se ordenan cronologicamente y se pueden agrupar por año, mes y día. También por categoría y etiqueta.

Comment: ah vale vale eso si lo sabía, no sabía si te referías a algo distinto. Gracias de nuevo por contestar!

Comment: Ok. Si te sirvió la respuesta, no olvides de marcarla como aceptada. Ambos ganamos reputación y medallas.

Comment: jajajaj vale soy nueva de hace 3 minutos aki.... donde se hace eso?

Comment: Debe haber una signo de aprobaci'on (en México le llamamos _palomita_ debajo del cero, a la izquierda de mi respuesta).